# What is the most effective way of reading the last line of a frequently updated log file with C?

Tags: c, logging

Preferably without external dependencies other than Windows 10.

Comment: By writing the line to a rewritten "most recent line" file as well as appending to the log file.

Comment: 1. Open file for reading. 2. Seek -500 bytes with respect to the *end* of the file. 3. Read 500 bytes into a buffer. 4. Search through that buffer for the last instance of `\n`. 5. Print out the rest of the buffer, or do whatever else it is you want to do with the last line.  (There's a race condition there if the file is updating *really* fast, which you can attempt to evade by reading more than 500 bytes in step 3.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: Your previous comment assumes that the last line does not have a newline character at the end. I believe it would make more sense to make the opposite assumption. Everything after the last newline character in the file should be considered part of a write in progress, and should therefore be ignored.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Whoops!  You're right.  (What was I thinking?) Lusvit: Amended step 4: Search through the buffer for the second-to-the-last `\n`.  (And then, for extra credit, print from there only up until the next `\n`, if you agree with Andreas's suggestion of ignoring partial writes in progress.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: I'm afraid that step 2 is not guaranteed to work with text streams. It is only guaranteed to work with binary streams. This applies both to ISO C and the Microsoft compiler. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=msvc-170) of the Microsoft compiler, `fseek( fp, -500, SEEK_END );` is not guaranteed to work on text streams.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I'm not exactly sure what will happen if, for example, byte offset `-500` from the end of the file has an `'\n'` character at that offset and a `'\r'` character immediately beforehand. Maybe it will work. However, it may also cause trouble if the log file has multibyte characters and offset `-500` is not the start of a character.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I suppose one could do worse than opening the file in binary mode.

Answer (score 1):

**Keep track of file offset of previous read**

To find the last line, retrieve offset of prior read from memory/auxiliary file/registry and walk to the end looking for the last line.  (If this is the first time, walk the entire file.)

When code reads the last line, record its offset in memory, in an auxiliary file or the registry for the next time.